# In recycler view , how do i create new card on every button or icon click in that card

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, cardview

my cardview consists of Some textviews and edittexts such as name,product,code, quantity, total.. etc. I want to create cardview in recycler view such that on every button click (or + icon click)  new card shows up. And on click of a final button below all the values of edittexts of all the cards get stored in an array list. I am quite confused how to do that. All the tutorials i see have either parsing or taking values from either database, but i want my cardviews to take values from user and store  as well as get created when new button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create layout file my_card_view_item.xml with your CardView and define adapter for your RecyclerView like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    List<String> myList;

    public MyAdapter(List<String> myList) {
        this.myList = myList;
    }

    public void addItem() {
        myList.add(new String());
        notifyItemInserted(myList.size() - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_card_view_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // bind your view

        holder.editText.setText(myList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myList.size();
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        EditText editText;
        Button btn_remove;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            editText = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            btn_remove = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_remove);

            editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    myList.set(getAdapterPosition(), charSequence.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });


            btn_remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    myList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(), myList.size());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

You need to store user entered data and show it in `onBindViewHolder` method to prevent data lost or data conflict.
Create instance of the adapter and set it to your RecyclerView.
Now on your + button's `OnClickListener` event, call your adapters `addItem` method:

```
    btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adapter.addItem();
        }
    });
```

Finaly you can get your all cards EditText value and store it in array:

```
    btn_final.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getItemCount(); i++) {
                EditText et = (EditText) recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(i).findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
                // Store et.getText() in your array
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: good ,but what is that someclass? and why u have created array list for it?

Comment: the program shows null pointer exception after execution on getItemcount()

Comment: if you do not need to bind some data to your view, you can remove list and only use `int` variable as ItemCount and increase it in addItem. I can edit my answer in that case if you want

Comment: i am little confused with this , although this is very nice solution, can i get ur email id if possible ?

Comment: and i have no data to be given to my cards, infact i have to only take data from my cards from editexts on cards... so what changes i must make to this code?

Comment: its working good,i have not included button click yet but i will do it,  just one more thing , when i created the myadapter object in mainactivity i passed 1 as argument in constructor. its working fine now , but after i include button click should i still keep it as 1 ? or what value should i write there?

Comment: the constractor input value is for determine how many items do we want in beginning. you can keep it as 1 for start.

Comment: hey, code is working fine , i have just one issue , i added delete button also just like add button.So when this delete is clicked the card gets deleted. But the problem is when i click the add button and when i filled the values of suppose 3 cards , then when i click delete button of card 2, first card 3 gets deleted , then again i click then the second card is deleted. So basically it starts deleting cards from downwards and not the actual card i click on. Another thing is when i click add after deleting, the same values of previous cards shows up in new card. Please help.

Comment: if u help me with just this , i would be glad. I have implemented delete button with notifyItemRemoved , it deletes the card but have the problem mentioned above (deletes the below cards first).

Comment: I edited my answer. you need to add remove button to `my_card_view_item` layout to remove exactly which item you want

Comment: Hey now what should i pass in the constructor of myadapter? and the  myList.add(new String()); in add item will be enough to add all the edittexts? and i have to write  editText.addTextChangedListener method for all edittexts right? please explain mate

Comment: You can create new List in this way `List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();` and add item to it like this `myList.add("");`.  
Now pass `myList` to constractor.  
Yes you must write `addTextChangedListener` method to all `EditText`'s.

Comment: exactly , thats what i thought and tried last night doing List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();  and then myList.add(");  but i see add written in red color then when i tried rebuild project it shows error identifier<> expected.

Comment: oh i figured out the mistake,  i declared in in mainacitivity rather than oncreate or some method, and thank you , its working very fine :) Thanks alot again , is there anyway can keep u in contact to learn more things? like email id or is their option of chat or follow here? thx again anyway :)

Comment: glad to help you :) i don't know if is here a way to be in touch with each other